# Ionic4: Not getting location if we minimize the app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, ionic-plugins

I am using Ionic4

Developing software that has to fetch the user's mobile location in both foreground and background mode.

1. I have used ionic 4 background mode to enable the app to run in background.
2. Using geolocation to fetch the mobile location.

This `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is working fine in foreground but not in background. But it returns value when we resume the app again.

I have tried a lot of ways to solve this issue but still it is giving the same. Can anyone help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
var options: PositionOptions = { enableHighAccuracy: true };

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(res => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        console.log('Get current position Success = ', res);
        this.getCurrentPosistion();
        // this.updateLocationInDatabase(location.coords);
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error('Error occurred = ', err);
      this.getCurrentPosistion();
    });
```

Comment: Use this Plugin for Background Location :https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

You can also use getCurrentLocation with watchposition because watchposition tracking location.

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {

// resp.coords.latitude

// resp.coords.longitude

}).catch((error) => {

console.log('Error getting location', error);

});

let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();

watch.subscribe((data) => {

// data can be a set of coordinates, or an error (if an error occurred).

// data.coords.latitude

// data.coords.longitude

});

Otherwise use Plugin

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/background-geolocation/